# Permission denied when I try to run a program assembled with the GNU assembler

Tags: permissions, gnu, assembly

I was testing the GNU assembler using intermediate code generated by gcc.  I don't really understand the GNU assembly syntax at all, though I could learn it at some point.  I ran the command `as hello.s` and then `as hello.s -o hello`.  When I ran the executable, it said "Permission denied".  Even when I tried to run it as root I still got the same message.  I ran `ls -l` to check the file permissions and the permission bits are normal (`rw-r--r--`).  What is going on here, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: `chmod +x hello`

Comment: Oh god, why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 2):

When you compile a source code file, the newly generated output binary file has the permissions `rw-r--r--` and is not executable, since there are no `x` in the string.

Make it executable by running

```
chmod +x hello
```

preceed the command with `sudo` if needed. After that, run the binary with `./hello`.